# How to turn off CSS validation warnings generated by Richfaces 4?

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I've a custom ecss file in my RichFaces 4 application. This ecss file has some warnings but I'm O.K. with them and don't want to fix this warnings.

I include this ecss file in my pages using;

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="myTheme.ecss" library="css" />
```

Everything works well but richfaces generates some warnings in the server log about ecss file.

> WARNING: Problem parsing 'css/sws/workstationTheme.ecss' resource: Ignoring the whole rule.
>   16-Jul-2012 10:26:59 org.richfaces.resource.CompiledCSSResource$ErrorHandlerImpl logException
>   WARNING: Problem parsing 'css/myTheme.ecss' resource: Error in attribute >selector. >Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: , "=", "]", "~=", "|=".

Is there a way to turn off this warnings, they appear every time when I access a JSF page so my server log is pretty full with them.

**Server**: Tomcat 7
**JSF Ver.** : javax.faces-2.1.8
**Rich Faces Ver**: 4.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Do you get the warnings when you restart your server?  That issue was a JIRA related to hot deployments that was supposedly fixed in 4.2.2.Final.  If you set javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE to Development in web.xml it's supposed to prevent generation of that exception.

Comment: Exceptions are thrown every time I refresh the page if the PROJECT_STAGE is set to Development. But if PROJECT_STAGE is set to Production then exceptions are thrown just for once and not thrown after page refreshes. However Production mode is almost useless since it comes with some downsides like I have to restart server after I modify the css. So I get used to live with css warnings